# Does Segmentation fault occurs due to accessing of large amount of memory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition

Insertion of large amount of random strings in Red black tree is giving segmentation fault in Ubuntu but the code work fine for insertion of few string(less than 50) . The code though works when it is compiled on windows.

```
#define ARR_SIZE(arr) (sizeof((arr))/sizeof((arr[0])))

void RandomStringtoRbtree(int n,RBT * t)
{
    char c[]="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
         int a  = rand()%(12);
         if(a<6)
         {
             a = a+6;
         }
         char * s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(a));
         for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
         {
             s[j] = c[rand()%(ARR_SIZE(c)-1)];
         }
         s[a]='\0';
         insert(t,s); // function to insert string formed in Red black tree
    }
}
```

Comment: "Amount" has nothing to do with it.  Segmentation faults occur when you access memory *that is not properly allocated*.  You can allocate 999999999 bytes and access 999999999 bytes, and all is well.  But if you allocate 3 bytes and access 4, boom.

Comment: Gourav, Note: `int a  = rand()%(12); if(a<6) { a = a+6; }` is functional like `int a  = 6 + rand()%6;`.

Comment: In this case, I'm guessing the seg fault is more likely to occur at some point *after* the out-of-bounds write occurs; if that `NUL` overwrites part of a pointer in the allocator's free list, then a future allocation that would have returned memory at `0xADD4ADD4` ends up returning memory at (on a little-endian system) `0xADD4AD00`, which is likely still a valid address (given page aligned blocks) but probably corresponds to something else important, and the new writes there corrupt more of the heap until eventually a pointer gets followed way outside the heap.

Comment: I will say that by hiding implementations of `insert`, `ARR_SIZE`, and `RBT`-related things in general, you're making it hard to identify all the possible causes of your problem. The single byte out-of-bounds write you show, and the inconsistent behavior by platform do match (the further you write out of bounds, the more reliable you'd expect the problem to become), but without an [MCVE], there's all sorts of potential problems we can't begin to identify.

Comment: Gourav, do not fundamentally change the question/code once answers arrive as it makes the answers invalid.  Post reverted.  Consider appending new info instead.

Answer (score 3):

The function has undefined behavior.

You allocated an array for `a` characters

```
     char * s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(a));
```

then all `a` characters of the array were filled.

```
     for(int j=0;j<a;j++)
     {
         s[j] = c[rand()%(ARR_SIZE(c)-1)];
     }
```

And after the loop you are accessing the memory outside the array

```
     s[a]='\0';
```

because the valid range of indices for this array is `[0, a )`.

You need to allocate an array for `a + 1` characters

```
     char * s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(a + 1));
```

It seems there is one more problem with the function. You are passing the pointer `t` by `value`  provided that `RBT` in turn is not a pointer type

```
void RandomStringtoRbtree(int n,RBT * t)
```

In this case any changes of the pointer t will not be seen outside the function.

Another problem can be related to this macro

```
#define ARR_SIZE(arr) (sizeof((arr))/sizeof((arr[0])))
```

If you pass an array to a function then it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. In this case the value of the macro `ARR_SIZE` used within the function can be invalid.

Comment: Hmm. While this is all correct, isn't `malloc` granularity typically at the 16 byte level? If the OP always allocates between 6 and 11 bytes, it would be safe on such an allocator. Probably varies by allocator, and the failing compilation targets would be using 8 byte granularity (so when `a` ends up being `8`, the NUL terminator stomps on bytes that are probably associated with a neighboring allocation's metadata, and boom).

Comment: @ShadowRanger The C standard says nothing about how the memory is allocated. So in any case it is undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't think the `RBT *t` is necessarily a problem; they're inserting `s` into `t`; many (most?) designs would not need to change the caller's pointer, it would just be changing data it points to to insert `s` into the tree.

Comment: I'm aware the C standard doesn't say anything. I'm just pointing out a possible reason why the behavior would differ; undefined behavior is bad, and you shouldn't do it, but it's also helpful to the OP to know *why* undefined behavior actually works sometimes (so they know that "It compiles and works on platform X" means a lot less than many people think it means, and why).

Comment: @ShadowRanger It is unclear because we do not see the code of the function insert. So I wrote that "it seems".

Comment: code is still giving segmentation fault after mallocing a+1 element

Comment: @Gourav Then we can't help you, because you have refused to show us the rest of your code.

Comment: @Gourav please [edit] and show a [mcve], otherwise the only thing we can tell you is: you did something wrong in some code you didn't show.

Comment: @Gourav I advice you to close the question, make changes I showed and check the code relative to my remarks and then ask a new question with your updated code.